# How to split String, convert to Numbers and Sum

Tags: javascript, string, split, sum, data-conversion

I have a function that I have modified to get a string (which consists of zeros and ones only).
The string (`timesheetcoldata`):

```
100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000
```

The string items (the numbers one and zero) will change every time the function is run.
It will always be the same length.
I have made the string above easier to see what I am trying to achieve.

I want to return the first character and then every 24th character (as in the variable colsCount in the function).
so, in the example above, it would return something like: `111111`

I then want to convert these characters to numbers (something like `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`).

I then want to sum these number together (so it would return, in the example: `6`).

I then want to check if the returned number matches the variable: `rowsCount`
or `true` if it does, `false` if it does not.

My function:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit").click(function(ev){

  var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
  var rowsCount = 6;
  var colsCount = 24;
  var timesheetrowsdata = "";
  var timesheetcoldata = "";

  for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
    rowStates = sheetStates[row];
    timesheetrowsdata += rowStates+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',');
  }

  timesheetcoldata = timesheetrowsdata.replace(/,/g, '');
  console.log(timesheetcoldata);
});
```

Thank you very much to both Rajesh and MauriceNino (and all other contributers).

With their code I was able to come up with the following working function:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit").click(function(ev){

  var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
  var rowsCount = 6;
  var timesheetrowsdata = "";
  var timesheetcoldata = "";

  for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
    rowStates = sheetStates[row];
    timesheetrowsdata += rowStates+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',');
  }

  timesheetcoldata = timesheetrowsdata.replace(/,/g, '');

var count = 0;
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i< timesheetcoldata.length; i+=24) {
  const num1 = Number(timesheetcoldata.charAt(i));
  list.push(num1);
  count += num1;
}

let isSameAsRowsCount = count == rowsCount;
console.log('Is Same? ', isSameAsRowsCount);

});
```

Comment: `"111111".split('').map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a+b)` - that covers most of your question

Comment: @JaromandaX You can just simplify it to "111111".length, since there's only going to be 1's. Or, if thats not the case, then `"111111".split('').reduce((a, b) => a++b, 0)`

Comment: yeah, I thought about that, but assumed it couldn't be as easy as `101010101.split('1').length - 1`  (assuming the 0's are 23 of them - code produces same result) :p

Comment: or `.reduce((a, b) => +a++b)` @Kobe

Comment: @JaromandaX There is no need to convert a to a number, since it already is one :)

Comment: not the first time around @Kobe ... both a and b will be sttrings... notice the complete lack of initial value in my suggestion :p

Comment: @JaromandaX I used `0` in mine  :P

Comment: Mine results in one less iteration - how may nanoseconds does that save @Kobe :D

Comment: at least 3 @JaromandaX :)

Comment: Thank you for all the ideas. Very useful. I have accepted an answer and have a working function will I will add to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step explanation, on what to do.

- Use `match()` to get every nth char
- Use `map()` to convert your array elements
- Use `reduce()` to sum your array elements

Everything needed to say is included in code comments:

```js
const testData = '100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000';

// Step 1) Create array of numbers from string
const dataArr = testData.match(/.{1,24}/g) // Split on every 24th char
                      .map(s => Number(s[0])) // Only take the first char as a Number

console.log(dataArr);

// Step 2) Sum array Numbers
let dataSum = dataArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b); // Add up all numbers

console.log(dataSum);

// Step 3) Compare your variables
let rowsCount = 123; // Your Test variable
let isSameAsRowsCount = dataSum == rowsCount;

console.log('Is Same? ', isSameAsRowsCount);
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much for this. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Minor suggestion. You can merge both `map` and return `(s) => Number(s[0])`. Also replacing all 0 might not be correct as OP is just looking for 1st character

Comment: You can even skip `map` completely and just put all the logic into the reduce to save an iteration. `.reduce((a,c) => a + +c[0], 0)`

Comment: or `.reduce((a,b) => +a++b)` @assoron

Comment: Sorry, this does not work if the string changes from the one in the example. It is good code and I can surely use it elsewhere. I will use the solution by Rajesh but use your isSameAsRowsCount  part as that works really well. Thank you.

Comment: You are right @assoron, but for clarity’s sake, I would argue that the performance increase here is noticeable, so I will keep it the way it is.

Comment: Just trying to get it functioning again. First problem was SyntaxError: redeclaration of var rowsCount and i am trying to remember how I got over that. Please bear with me a few minutes.

Comment: @flakie thats because you already have `rowsCount`. Just remove `let rowsCount = 123;` from my code. It was for testing purposes.

Comment: Apologies. It is all working now and working very well. I am new to this and probably added in something else that broke your code. Now I am at a quandary of which code to use. I never expected to get any choices, let alone such good ones. Should I delete my comment it is not working?

Comment: No problem, I am here to help, not to blame. Use whatever feels more easy for you. The performance on the other will be slightly better (not that it matters much). You can't delete your comments anyways, because its older than 5 minutes, but if you could, you wouldn't need, because they add value to the conversation. Have a good time learning to program! :) @flakie

Comment: Thank you very much. Could I please ask a question. Does the 1 in (testData.match(/.{1,24}) indicate the starting point in the string, then use that character and then every 24th? If so I will use your code as later I will be using longer strings and will need to start at different positions.

Comment: If you have a question about regex, just use this site: [Link](https://regex101.com/r/9nem5l/1) (Test Example of your project). What it means is, that it matches any character 1 to 24 times. And it results in any number of strings (thus resulting in an array). The first number is the minumum and the second is the maximum. If you want to match *exactly* 24 characters you might use `/.{24,24}`. @flakie

Comment: Thank you very much. Looking at that now.

Comment: No problem! @flakie

Answer (score 1):

You can always rely on traditional `for` for such action. Using functional operations can be more readable but will be more time consuming(*though not by much*).

You can try this simple algo:

1. Create a list that will hold all numbers and a `count` variable to hold sum.
2. Loop over string. As string is fixed, you can set the increment factor to the count(`24`).
3. Convert the character at given index and save it in a variable.
4. Push this variable in list and also compute sum at every interval.

At the end of this loop, you have both values.

```js
var string = '100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000';
var count = 0;
var list = [];
for(var i = 0; i< string.length; i+=24) {
  const num1 = Number(string.charAt(i));
  list.push(num1);
  count += num1;
}

console.log(list, count)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This works even better than the answer i accepted. I will choose this answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jaromanda mentioned, you can use the following to done this.

```js
const string = '100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000';

const value = string.split('').filter((e,i)=> !(i%24)).reduce((acc,cur)=> acc+ (+cur), 0);

console.log(value);
```

Comment: or `.reduce((a, b)=> +a + +b)`